# Tables created with sqlalcheny not showing up in Amazon RDS

Tags: pandas, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

Apologies, I am new to this and thank you in advance for any insights. I am creating `Postgresql` tables using `sqlalchemy` for `Amazon RDS`. The tables are not showing up when I try to use `Quicksight` or in `SQL Workbench`. The code I am using is (I also echo'ed the engine and everything seems to be working):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect, text
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, Text, String, DateTime
    
ENDPOINT="db_instance_name.csnul5z77jon.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
PORT="5432"
USR="xxx"
PSSWD="xxx"
DBNAME="postgres"

    #conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='my_database' user='postgres' password='secret'
conn_string = "postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(USR, PSSWD, ENDPOINT, PORT, DBNAME)
print(conn_string)

    # create engine
try:
    
    engine = create_engine(conn_string)
    print("connection OK")
    
except Exception as e:
    print("Database connection failed due to {}".format(e))  

df_pull_check.to_sql(
    'popular_102',
    engine,
    schema = 'public',
    if_exists='replace',
    index=False,
    chunksize=500,
    dtype={
        "date": DateTime,
        "symbol": Text,
        "name":  Text,
        "start_popularity": Integer,
        "popularity_difference": Float       
    }
)

with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execute('ALTER TABLE popular_102 ADD COLUMN record_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY')
```

When I check the table names using the code below, table `popular_102` shows up:

```
 inspector = inspect(engine)
 table_names = inspector.get_table_names()
 print(table_names)
```

I checked to make sure the data is there using the code below, and it is:

```
with engine.connect() as con:
    df_sql = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM popular_102', con)
    df_sql = pd.DataFrame(df_sql, con)
```

I also changed `retrieve` to `append` in `to_sql` in the first code section above just to trigger an error, and an error does show up in AWS log:

```
[12959]:ERROR: column "record_id" of relation "popular_102" already exists
2020-07-13 01:02:31 xxxxx@postgres:[12959]:STATEMENT: ALTER TABLE popular_102 ADD COLUMN record_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
```

However, the table never makes it to `Amazon Quicksight` or `SQL Workbench`. I am able to create a table in `SQL Workbench`, `commit to Amazon RDS`, and `access it in Quicksight`.

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Comment: seems like you are using default database `postgres` did you speicfy database during RDS launch?

Comment: that did it... Thank you!

Comment: Great, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using default database. To resolve the issue do the following step

- Enter RDS console
- Specify initial Database Name

Once Database is ready to accept connection use `newly` created database name that we have created in step 2.

You can look into further into this [step by step article](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/)

Update the code to point to new Database

```
ENDPOINT="db_instance_name.csnul5z77jon.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
PORT="5432"
USR="xxx"
PSSWD="xxx"
DBNAME="mydb"
```